# using prisma and postgres, having trouble storing images as base64. cannot use cdn/cloudinary

Tags: postgresql, next.js, base64, prisma, next.js13

have created a screenshot feature in nextjs app. code below ->

```
const handleSingleSS = async (index) => {
const element = document.getElementById(`video-stream${index}`);

  if (element) {
  const canvas = await html2canvas(element);
  const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/webp");
  console.log("img", imgData);
  const base64Response = await fetch(imgData);

  sendImageToDatabase(base64Response.url, nodeId);
} else {
  console.log("element not found");
}}
```

capture screenshot function then calls sendImagetoDatabase code below ->

```
export const sendImageToDatabase = async (imageFile, nodeId) => {
  try {
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", imageFile);
formData.append("nodeId", nodeId);

const response = await axios.post("/api/captureScreenshots", formData, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
});

if (response.status === 200) {
  console.log(response.data);
  console.log("Image successfully sent to the database.");
} else {
  console.error("Failed to send image to the database.");
}
} catch (error) {
 console.error("Error sending image to the database:", error);
 }
};
```

api endpoint ->

```
export const sendImageToDatabase = async (imageFile, nodeId) => {
try {
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", imageFile);
formData.append("nodeId", nodeId);

const response = await axios.post("/api/captureScreenshots", formData, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
});

if (response.status === 200) {
  console.log(response.data);
  console.log("Image successfully sent to the database.");
} else {
  console.error("Failed to send image to the database.");
}
} catch (error) {
console.error("Error sending image to the database:", error);
 }
};
```

model schema ->

```
model Screenshots {
 id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
 image Json
 time DateTime @default(now())
 nodeId     Int
 node       Node     @relation(fields: [nodeId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

when api request is made is stays pending, i think that is due to the size of the data. i tried with small string it worked. was earlier sending the base64data not unit8array it was also not working/ getting stored in db. earlier the schema for image was also set to string. to what format should i convert the data to store it into db. or if any way to store base64 only?